# Storage space used by records based on the number of fields completed

Tags: lightning, data-storage, storage-limit

I'd like to know if there is a difference on storage usage if all the fields on a record have data in them (to the max characters) vs. a record where only a couple of fields have data in them?

Comment: You are normally good about researching basic topics before posting here. When googling the title will yield an answer to the question, however, it is hard to not vote down for lack of research.

Comment: @AdrianLarson you meanie ;-) ... surely a friendly warning would suffice. my excused it that I am crazy busy today, and this was a non critical piece of information to learn, so I didn't have time to look. In hindsight, I should have done a cursory Google first. My bad.

Comment: That is the warning. :) It's just 2 internet points, it doesn't seem too harsh in the grand scheme of things. I have a lot of data points that you are a solid, productive member of this community and one post certainly won't change that. My reaction may have been stronger for someone who has a bad track record already.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Aye aye captain! Thank you for your leniency :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No a record will take 2KB space irrespective of whether you fill one field or all fields.

Read [Salesforce record size overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193871&language=en_US&type=1) on how salesforce calculates record storage space.

Estimated storage for records by object type:

- Leads -- 2KB
- Contacts -- 2KB
- Accounts -- 2KB
- Person Accounts - 4KB
- Opportunities -- 2KB
- Forecasts -- 2KB
- Events -- 2KB
- Tasks -- 2KB
- Cases -- 2KB
- Case Team Member -- 2KB
- Solutions -- 2KB
- Notes -- 2KB
- Custom Reports -- 2KB
- Campaigns -- 8KB
- Campaign Members -- 1KB
- Contracts -- 2KB
- Google Docs -- 2KB
- Quotes -- 2KB
- Tags: unique tags -- 2KB
- Custom Objects -- 2KB
- Quote Template Rich Text Data -- 2KB
- Articles -- 4KB*
- Email Message -- 2KB**
- Person Accounts -- 4KB***

> - *May vary based on the content of rich text area (RTA) fields. Images from (RTA) are stored in file storage area.
> - **May vary dependent on whether the email message is HTML. For example, a 100KB email message will consume 100KB of data storage
>     space. Text only emails will take less than HTML due to only being the
>     body text and not the html code and text version as well.
> - ***Person Accounts consume roughly 4KB. They are a junction of two individual records, an Account and a Contact. For example, 500,000
>     person accounts will require around 2GB of storage. Storage needed =
>     (500000 X 4KB)/1024 = 1953.125 MB which when further divided by 1024 =
>     1.9073 GB which is around 2GB.